# How can i install pattern library in pattern?

Tags: python, nltk, importerror, python-pattern

```py
ImportError: Pattern library is not installed. Pattern library is needed in order to use lemmatize function
```

This is what the error was shown while i'm using python.

```
def process_texts(texts):
    texts = [[word for word in line if word not in stops] for line in texts]
    texts = [bigram[line] for line in texts]
    texts = [[word.decode("utf-8").split('/')[0] for word in lemmatize(' '.join(line), allowed_tags=re.compile('(NN)'), min_length=5)] for line in texts]
    return texts

import re
train_texts = process_texts(list_of_simple_preprocess_data)
```

I had used `install pattern3` but still I was facing the same error .

Comment: Do you mean `pip install pattern3`? What OS are you at? which python version do you run your code under?